# Не могу достать LatLng из geocode

Tags: google-maps-api

пытаюсь сделать кастомную карту в которой можно будет проложить маршрут от точки А до точки B.

```
var start_point;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': 'Москва'
    }, function (results) {
        start_point = results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(start_point); //тут выводит координаты
    });
console.log(start_point); //undefind
```

Почему я не могу перезаписать переменную?

Comment: область видимости не та

Comment: кстати не знаешь как расстояние между ними найти ?)

Comment: знаю, могу скинуть пример

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sayoviseda/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: если не сложно ,я нашел один в документации но там слишком каверезна )

Comment: ну этот метод по легче моего )

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/closures#доступ-ко-внешним-переменным

Comment: Найдешь решение на свой вопрос дай нам знать )